# Finding a surjection $f:\Bbb N \to \Bbb N$ such that every integer has an infinite set of preimages by $f$

Tags: functions

All I could come up with is:

$f$ is a surjection such that
$f:\Bbb N \to \Bbb N \\
n \mapsto f(2n)$

but it's not well defined.

Any suggessions?

Answer (score 4):

Quick example:  For a prime $p$, map $p^n$ to $n$.  Map any non-prime power to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

One more example. Consider a function that does the following:

- If $0 \leq x \leq 9$ it maps $x$ to itself, i.e. $f:x\rightarrow x$
- Otherwise it removes the first digit of the $x$, e.g. $f : 10023 \mapsto 23$, $f: 12 \mapsto 2$, etc.

Why this works?
Consider any number $n$ that has digits $~\overline{n_1n_2\dots n_k}$.
Its preimage contains numbers $~\overline{1n_1n_2\dots n_k}$, $~\overline{10n_1n_2\dots n_k}$, $~\overline{100n_1n_2\dots n_k}$, etc.
Namely, there are infinitely many numbers mapped to $n$.

Answer (score 0):

map to
$$ 1,2;1,2,3;1,2,3,4;1,2,3,4,5; 1,2,3,4,5,6; 1,2,3,4,5,6,7; ...  $$

so when the index $n$ is a triangular number the image is one.

For $k > 1,$ eventually index $T_j + k - 1$ for large enough $j$